# Remove outer array containing arrays with objects, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, flatten

I'm getting back an array which looks like this:

```
[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
```

I can get it to look like this with map():

```
[ [{...}], [{...}], [{...}] ]
```

I am having trouble getting this result:

```
[{...}], [{...}], [{...}]
```

I just need to remove the outer/parent array. I have tried flatten, flattenDepth, and reduce, however, I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `array = array[0]`?

Comment: Can you post the actual expected output with some sample data? `[{...}], [{...}], [{...}]` neither a valid object nor an array

Comment: You want to wrap each object  element from your original array in its own 1 element array?

Comment: What is `[{...}], [{...}], [{...}]` supposed to be? 3 separate variables? An array (that's what you already have in the 2nd code block)?

Answer (score 2):

The format you're asking for as output is a bunch of arrays with no containing object or array. That's not a thing you can do, at least not in one variable. The middle example is probably just fine for whatever you're using it for -- you can use `forEach` to handle each inner array element separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop an you will get what you want

**Example:**

```js
const arr = [
  [{}],
  [{}],
  [{}]
]


console.log(arr.map(el => ` This an array of object  ===> ${el}`))
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe take a look at the ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), it looks somewhat like what you're asking for. Be aware that it might not be widely supported though.

You could also try [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply), that takes a `this` object (which can be null) and an array with arguments and calls a function with them (if that's what you need).